# Need an API For a accepting payments on behalf of third party

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I need help finding a payment processor. We need to be able to accept payments from buyers for physical merchandise, and have the funds deposited in our customer's accounts. We don't really wish to hang onto the funds and transfer them, but if that's our only choice then so be it.

We've been looking at the Paypal API, but I don't seem to understand how to accomplish this scenario.

Any help or advice appreciated!

EDIT:
We want to avoid having our customers open up a party other than us. Stripe requires that our customers create an account with them as well. Kind of a pain in the butt for someone hoping to sign up with us quickly...

Comment: Stripe shouldn't require your customers to create an account. It's simply a payment processor. You give it credit card information and the amount to charge and it does it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the money to go directly to your customer then they're going to need an account of their own for you to send that money to.  Not sure what else you're expecting..??

You can tie this into the sign-up on your own site, though, using the [Adaptive Accounts API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-accounts).  Stripe has something similar called [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/blog/stripe-connect).

Stripe makes you wait a week for your money, though, so I'd recommend going with PayPal.

Comment: We went with Stripe Connect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have your customer open a Paypal account for their own use and direct payments to that account from your software.

Comment: :/ we'd like to not have to have to open an account with a third party. We want the whole process to be a one stop shop